# How can I access this div statement with Beautiful Soup?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

First of all, I am not a coder so sorry in advance for a possible bad explanation.

I want to retrieve the html code inside the following div statement using Beautiful soup:

```
<div x-y-z> == $0
```

I usually would retrieve html code in soup like the following:

```
html = soup.find("div", class_="x-y-z")
```

My problem here is that there is no class or id or anything included in the div statement, only the "x-y-z" of which I dont know what it is.

How can I retrieve the html code from the above-shown div with Beautiful soup? I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSS selector:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup("<div x-y-z>Something</div>", "html.parser")

print(soup.select_one("div[x-y-z]"))
```

Prints:

```html
<div x-y-z="">Something</div>
```

---

Or `bs4` API:

```py
print(soup.find("div", {"x-y-z": True}))
```

Prints:

```html
<div x-y-z="">Something</div>
```

Comment: I used the second solution and it worked. Thanks!